# How to fix bug with extracting numbers from links?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a sheet with 4 tabs. Tab 2 column A consists of a bunch of links and I am trying to extract some numbers from them. I want to take the number that comes after the last "/" from each cell, then go find that number in (tab 4, row # (wherever I find that number), column A). Then I want to copy (tab 4, row #, column E) and paste it in (tab 2, active row, column I). I don't know how long the number is, but it could be up to 4 digits. The links follow the format of "blahblah/[my number]blahblah" where the blahblah parts can have letters, numbers, and symbols. The number always comes after the last / though.

When I run my code, after the first entry from tab 2 it can't find any number that matches from tab 4. I think this must be because I am not saving my number correcting with the InStrRev and IsNumeric portion, but I'm not that familiar with vba and don't know how to start fixing it.

```
Sub FindWidget()

    Dim ctr As Integer
    'Dim numToFind As Integer'
    Dim numAsStr As String
    Dim str As String
    Dim subStr As String
    Dim count As Integer

    Worksheets(2).Activate
    Range("A2").Select
    numAsString = ""

    Do Until ActiveCell.Value = ""
        str = ActiveCell.Value 'current cell'
        ctr = InStrRev(str, "/", -1) ''find the last forward slash'
        ctr = ctr + 1 'position of number'
        subStr = Mid(str, ctr, 4) 'max number length is 4'
        For count = 1 To Len(subStr)
            If IsNumeric(Mid(subStr, count, 1)) = True Then
                numAsString = numAsString & Mid(subStr, count, 1)
            End If
        Next

        'numToFind = CInt(numAsString)'
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 8).Select  'move to this row, col 9'

        Worksheets(4).Activate
        Range("A2").Select
        Do Until ActiveCell.Value = ""
            If ActiveCell.Value = numAsString Then
                ActiveCell.Offset(0, 4).Select
                Worksheets(4).ActiveCell.Copy Worksheets(2).ActiveCell
                ActiveCell.Offset(0, -4).Select
            End If
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
        Loop

        Worksheets(2).Activate
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select 'next'
    Loop


End Sub
```

After I run the code I end up in tab 2, row 3, col I and the active cell in tab 4 is at the end of col A

Comment: try setting the `numAsString` variable to `numAsString =""` at the begining of the do loop  because `numAsString = numAsString & Mid(subStr, count, 1)`  will concatenate all the values on all the rows as the do loop continues

Comment: Thank you! I got that part to work now and now everything works but my copy paste. Any idea what could be going wrong there? I keep getting error 438 "Object doesn't support this property or method"

Comment: try using this instead the copy paste method  `ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(2).Cells(1, 1) = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1)`,so you can use a single line